# How to make a column a primary key so duplicate records cannot be added

Tags: duplicate

I have a text column called JPPNum, and I want to make it so a user cannot add the same JPP Number if the record with that JPP number is already in there. So no duplicate on JPP NUm, how would I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select **Enforce unique values** in columns settings.

More info in [MSDN: Enforcing Uniqueness in Column Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).